# jBPM 5 - sessioninfo and processinfo not getting persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, jboss7.x, jbpm

I am trying to execute a simple Human Task bpmn on jBPMv5.x deployed on JBoss7 Application Server. Database is Postgresql V9.2. I find that tasks are getting committed to the database but sessioninfo and processinfo is never getting inserted to respective tables even after invoking ksession.dispose().

Please let me know what I am missing.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="org.drools.persistence.jpa"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/ProcessInstanceInfo.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/ExtraIndexes.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>


        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="jbpm" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
                value="false" />


            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.task"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>org.jbpm.task.Attachment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.BooleanExpression</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Content</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Delegation</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotification</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotificationHeader</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Escalation</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Group</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.I18NText</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Notification</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.OnAllSubTasksEndParentEndStrategy</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.OnParentAbortAllSubTasksEndStrategy</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.PeopleAssignments</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Reassignment</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Status</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.SubTasksStrategy</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.Task</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.TaskData</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.task.User</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="jbpm" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
                value="false" />


            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**ProcMgmtBean**

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@Singleton(name = "ProcMgmt")
public class ProcMgmtBean implements IProcMgmt, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "org.jbpm.task")
    private EntityManagerFactory emftask;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "org.drools.persistence.jpa")
    private EntityManagerFactory emfpersist;

    public void registerTaskService(StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession) {

        Properties properties = getProperties();
        System.setProperty("jbpm.usergroup.callback", properties.getProperty(
                "taskservice.usergroupcallback",
                "org.jbpm.task.service.DefaultUserGroupCallbackImpl"));




        System.out.println("Inside register task service, create new task service");

        TaskService taskService = new TaskService(emftask,
                SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener());

        System.out.println("Task service instantiated, creating handler");

        SyncWSHumanTaskHandler handler = new SyncWSHumanTaskHandler(
                new LocalTaskService(taskService), ksession);
        handler.connect();
        System.out.println("Handler connected");
        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task",
                handler);
        System.out.println("Task service registered");

    }

    protected Environment createEnvironment() {
        Environment env = EnvironmentFactory.newEnvironment();
        env.set(EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, emfpersist);


        return env;
    }

    public StatefulKnowledgeSession newStatefulKnowledgeSession(
            KnowledgeBase kbase) {
        return loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase, -1);
    }

    public StatefulKnowledgeSession loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(
            KnowledgeBase kbase, int sessionId) {

        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession;
        Environment env = createEnvironment();

        Properties sessionconfigproperties = new Properties();
        sessionconfigproperties.put("drools.processInstanceManagerFactory", 
           "org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.DefaultProcessInstanceManagerFactory");
        sessionconfigproperties.put("drools.processSignalManagerFactory", 
           "org.jbpm.process.instance.event.DefaultSignalManagerFactory");

        KnowledgeSessionConfiguration config = KnowledgeBaseFactory
                .newKnowledgeSessionConfiguration(sessionconfigproperties);


        if (sessionId == -1) {
            System.out.println("session id = -1");
            ksession = JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase,
                    config, env);
        } else {
            System.out.println("session id = " + sessionId);
            ksession = JPAKnowledgeService.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(
                    sessionId, kbase, config, env);
        }

        return ksession;
    }
}
```

**Invocation servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside doGet");
        initiateWF();
    }

    private void initiateWF() {

        System.out.println("Init");
        KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();

        IProcMgmt processMgmt = null;

        System.out.println("START OF CREATION OF PROC MANAGEMENT");

        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            processMgmt = (IProcMgmt) ctx
                    .lookup("java:global...");
            System.out.println("Proc management created "
                    + (processMgmt != null));
        } catch (NamingException e1) {
            System.out.println("Fail to create Proc mgmt");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("read kb complete");
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = processMgmt
                .newStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase);
        int sessionId = ksession.getId();
        System.out.println("session id:" + sessionId );

        System.out
                .println("got new ksession, starting to register task service");
        processMgmt.registerTaskService(ksession);
        System.out.println("task service registered");

        // start a new process instance


        //Each Command will generate an interaction
        System.out.println(">>> Let's Create Process Instance");
        ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.createProcessInstance("com.sample.bpmn.humanhello",null);
        System.out.println(">>> Let's Start the Process Instance");
        long processInstanceId = processInstance.getId();
        System.out.println(" processInstanceId:" + processInstanceId);
        String processId = processInstance.getProcessId();
        System.out.println(" process id:" + processId);
        ksession.startProcess(processId);



        System.out.println(">>> Disposing Session");
        ksession.dispose();




    }

    private  KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase()  {
        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory
                .newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory
                .newClassPathResource("jbpm/com.sample.HumanHello.bpmn2"),
                ResourceType.BPMN2);
        return kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a local task manager, there's no need to create a separate emf for the engine and task service.  Could you check if using the same emf for both the runtime engine and task service changes anything?  If not, could you attach the server log, as it seems you have sql output set to true, which might be useful.

Kris

Comment: I tried using same emf and different emf with same result. the sample I pasted is with different emf. I will share log shortly

Comment: Logs are too big  and could not paste in the message body. Uploaded to https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2f3rkh0ywu5mh3/server-using-start-process.log    Below log is if I call startProcessInstance instead of StartProcess.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jr1gihlsl9pnsj/server-using-ksession.startProcessInstance.log     let me know if you face issue accessing the logs